# Speed up macros involving `\text` when using `microtype` and `newtxmath`

Tags: microtype, newtxmath

I have the following macro that is invoked *a lot* (2871 for a document of 8 pages), because it is generated by a preprocessor:

```
\newcommand{\varid}[1]{\textbf{#1}}}
```

Using the profiler library of `tikz`, I figured out that this macro accounts for 2/3 of compile time, where another 1/6 is due to the preamble.

I also could pinpoint this to the use of the packages `microtype` and `newtxmath`, which are both included in `acmart`.

Here are a few observations:

1. If I wrap `\textbf` for `\mbox`, performance is good.
2. If I get rid of the dependency on either `microtype` or `newtxmath`, performance is good.
3. Of course I can work around this problem; I just think it doesn't *need* to be so slow, as evident by (1) and (2). And it took me a lot of time to figure out what is wrong in the first place.

How can I speed up `\textbf` (I'm actually using `\textsf{\textsl{#1}}`, not that it makes a difference in performance)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{profiler}

\newcommand{\varid}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\pgfprofilenewforcommand{\varid}{1}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{c}
\varid {$x$}\\
\varid {$x$}\\
\varid {$x$}\\
\varid {$x$}\\
\varid {$x$}\\
... repeat ad lib, I had about 700 lines ...
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

For me, this spends 2/3 of time in `\varid`:

```
...
Overfull \vbox (16549.99998pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [2]
pgflibraryprofiler: relative values are measured against the totaltime of `main job'.
 pgflibraryprofiler(main job) {total time=0.99443sec; (99.99847%) self time=0.084sec; (8.44574%) invocations=1; }
 pgflibraryprofiler(preamble) {total time=0.24377sec; (24.51324%) self time=0.24377sec; (24.51324%) invocations=1; }
 pgflibraryprofiler(<CS>varid) {total time=0.66666sec; (67.03796%) self time=0.66666sec; (67.03796%) invocations=696; }
(./mwe.aux)
...
```

Furthermore, according to `\pgfprofilenewforcommand` and piping the resulting log through `tr '%.s'`, it appears that some calls take longer than others; up to 150ms per call.

What can I do about this? Is this a known interaction?

Comment: why are you using  \text so often at all? And why do you switch in and out of mathmode like that? In your example I would only use \tau and \bm\tau.

Comment: Well, not all my invokations are going into math mode like that; the majority in fact isn't. Besides; why would switching from math to text and into math be slower *only if I include these particular packages*?

Comment: Basically because `amsmath` makes `\text... `macros work in sub- and superscripts. That's a lot of work.

Comment: @campa Aha, that's good to know. But does that mean it doesn't work outside `amsmath`? I removed `\RequirePackage{microtype}` from `acmart.cls` and I can't make out a meaningful difference. Here is a diff, for reference: https://draftable.com/compare/vUGXFHHKZYSR

Comment: Try `a_{\textrm{b}}` with and without `amsmarh` and you'll see...

Comment: Can you modify the preprocessor to output `\varid{x}` instead of `\varid{$x$}` which is really the problem? Not only a much more efficient solution exists, but you can also achieve the objective of printing `x` in slanted sans serif type, which the current state won't allow.

Comment: Yes, that is my current workaround, and it is of course simple to implement. `\varid` sets a color and changes the font; I now factored out `\varcolor` and do `\varcolor{x}` instead.

Comment: But I feel like this discussion is beside the point: Of course I can find workarounds now that I spent hours debugging to find the root of this issue.
But I'd rather not have spent so many hours debugging.
So my question is: Why is `\textbf{$x$}` accepted, reportedly produces the same output as `x`, but *performs much worse*? If a human can reason that `\textbf{$x$}` is the same as `x`, then surely the TeX compiler can as well! It is just bad lang/compiler design. Now, there might be technical reasons why the TeX compiler can't do that, but in that case it could produce *at least* a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\varid {$ {\tau }$}` will produce the same output as `\tau` but *much* slower.
`\text` sets its argument 4 times in display, text, script and script script styles and for each of those it has to set up all the math fonts so even without microtype it's is going to be many times slower.

`\tracingall` length is a fairly good approximation to actual runtime comparison

if you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\tracingall

$
\message{===}\tau\message{===}\text{$\tau$}\message{===}
$

\tracingnone

\end{document}
```

then between the first two `===` there is just 1 line

```
{\mathchar"11C}
```

Between the second two there are over 3 thousand lines

```
~.\text ->\protect \text  
{\relax}

~..\text  ->\ifmmode \expandafter \text@ \else \expandafter \mbox \fi 
{\ifmmode: (level 1) entered on line 8}
{true}
{\expandafter}
{\else: \ifmmode (level 1) entered on line 8}
{\fi: \ifmmode (level 1) entered on line 8}

~..\text@ #1->{\mathchoice {\textdef@ \displaystyle \f@size {#1}}{\textdef@ \te
xtstyle \f@size {\firstchoice@false #1}}{\textdef@ \textstyle \sf@size {\firstc
hoice@false #1}}{\textdef@ \textstyle \ssf@size {\firstchoice@false #1}}\check@
mathfonts }
#1<-$\tau $
{begin-group character {}
{entering math group (level 2) at line 8}
{\mathchoice}
{entering math choice group (level 3) at line 8}

~..\textdef@ #1#2#3->\hbox {{\everymath {#1}\let \f@size #2\selectfont #3}}
#1<-\displaystyle 
#2<-\f@size 
#3<-$\tau $

.....

~..\mv@bold@reset ->
```

As the end result of the two expressions are the same, simply removing all instances of
`\text{$..$}` or `\textbf{$..$}` will make things much faster.

Comment: See my updated Q, where I used `\varid{$x$}` instead of `\varid{$\tau$}`. Also note that wrapping `\textbf{}` in `\mbox{}` resolves the issue; I doubt that length of the trace would change much

Comment: Well, actually the length of the diff *changes much* when I wrap it in an `\mbox`. Regardless; I don't see why I have to pay so much without so much as a warning

Comment: `\varid{$x$}` is exactly the same as using `\tau`  it produces the same as `x` but  many times slower,  `\mbox` changes things completely the trace would be just a few lines with `\mbox{\textbf{$x}}` @SebastianGraf  "I doubt that length of the trace would change much " try it:-)

Comment: @SebastianGraf why do you want `\textbf{$x$}` at all, given that it is just `x` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried :) I was surprised to see there *is* a difference. Anyway, I guess non-compositional performance is the TeX world we live in, and your explanation is great, so I'll accept your answer

Comment: `\textbf{$x$}` being the same as `x` is _by design` not a flaw, math does not pick up the current text font. so the fact that you are in a bold region does not change the math. @SebastianGraf

Comment: Yes, that much is clear. But my point is: If a human can figure out that those terms are equal _by design_, then so could the TeX compiler. Instead, it does not even produce a warning and I lost a few hours trying to find the root of the problem (e.g., the MWE).

Comment: @SebastianGraf  not  really, it's just user error. any  none trivial case all that code would be doing something, if you had text{ab $x$} for example. if you explicitly enable text processing that does nothing but switch back out of text then you are forcing a lot of computation. same as if you program  loop and only use the last iteration. it's hard to optimise these things away especially as there is no compiler it's just a macro expansion language so there is no chance to pre examine and remove dead loops

Comment: Well, let's agree to disagree on whether it is feasible for the TeX compiler to detect `\text{$blah$}`. I'll remember not to switch too often into math mode from `\text{}` in the future. Thanks for your answer and your patience :)

Comment: @SebastianGraf it would be a bad trade to slow down processing for everyone just to check for a case that only happens for user error, there is no reason to ever use text in that way.